# how to assign data into hash from an input file

Tags: perl

I am new to perl. 
Inside my input file is :

```
james1
84012345

aaron5
2332111 42332
2345112 18238

wayne[2]
3505554
```

Question: I am not sure what is the correct way to get the input and set the name as key and number as values. example "james" is key  and "84012345" is the value.

This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
my $input= $ARGV[0];
my %hash;
open my $data , '<', $input or die " cannot open file : $_\n";
my @names  = split ' ', $data;
my @values = split ' ', $data;
@hash{@names} = @values;
print Dumper \%hash;
```

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: Sorry melpomene,  this is the expected result.  

%hash(
    james1 =>[
        84012345
    ],
    aaron5 => [
        2332111,
        42332,
        2345112,
        18238
    ]
    'wayne[2]' => [
        3505554,
    ]
)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'mma go over your code real quick:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
```

`-w` is not recommended. You should `use warnings;` instead (which you're already doing, so just remove `-w`).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

Very good.

```
use Data::Dumper;
my $input= $ARGV[0];
```

OK.

```
my %hash;
```

Don't declare variables before you need them. Declare them in the smallest scope possible, usually right before their first use.

```
open my $data , '<', $input or die " cannot open file : $_\n";
```

You have a spurious space at the beginning of your error message and `$_` is unset at this point. You should include `$input` (the name of the file that failed to open) and `$!` (the error reason) instead.

```
my @names  = split ' ', $data;
my @values = split ' ', $data;
```

Well, this doesn't make sense. `$data` is a filehandle, not a string. Even if it were a string, this code would assign the same list to both `@names` and `@values`.

```
@hash{@names} = @values;
print Dumper \%hash;
```

---

My version (untested):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

@ARGV == 1
    or die "Usage: $0 FILE\n";
my $file = $ARGV[0];

my %hash;
{
    open my $fh, '<', $file or die "$0: can't open $file: $!\n";
    local $/ = '';
    while (my $paragraph = readline $fh) {
        my @words = split ' ', $paragraph;
        my $key = shift @words;
        $hash{$key} = \@words;
    }
}

print Dumper \%hash;
```

The idea is to set `$/` (the [input record separator](https://perldoc.pl/perlvar#IO::Handle-%3Einput_record_separator(-EXPR-))) to `""` for the duration of the input loop, which makes `readline` return whole paragraphs, not lines.

The first (whitespace separated) word of each paragraph is taken to be the key; the remaining words are the values.

Answer (score 0):

You have opened a file with `open()` and attached the file handle to `$data`. The regular way of reading data from a file is to loop over each line, like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl                                           
use strict;                                                   
use warnings;                                                 
use Data::Dumper;                                             

my $input = $ARGV[0];
my %hash;
open my $data , '<', $input or die " cannot open file : $_\n";
while (my $line = <$data>) {
    chomp $line; # Removes extra newlines (\n)
    if ($line) { # Checks if line is empty
        my ($key, $value) = split ' ', $line;
        $hash{$key} = $value;
    }
}
print Dumper \%hash;
```

Comment: I don't think the split is going to work as the data has keys and values on multiple lines.

Comment: @JGNI, I know, but I think the question was geared towards general knowledge of how to parse files. Parsing inconsistent input is always a pain, and in this case, there was no obvious way to tell which data should be keys and which should be values.

Comment: @Ricaz his input data looks like key, new line, (value, new line) +, blank line. So you can split each record on the blank line when reading in the data and then use a split on `/[ \n]/` taking the first element as the key and all the others as values

Answer (score 0):

OK, +1 for using `strict` and `warnings`.

First Take a look at the `$/` variable for controlling how a file is broken into records when it's read in.

`$data` is a file handle you need to extract the data from the file, if it's not to big you can load it all into an array, if it's a large file you can loop over each record at a time. See the `<>` operator in `perlop`

Looking at you code it appears that you want to end up with the following data structure from your input file

```
%hash(
    james1 =>[
        84012345
    ],
    aaron5 => [
        2332111,
        42332,
        2345112,
        18238
    ]
    'wayne[2]' => [
        3505554,
    ]
)
```

See `perldsc` on how to do that.

All the documentation can be read using the `perldoc` command which comes with Perl. Running `perldoc` on its own will give you some tips on how to use it and running `perldoc perldoc` will give you possibly far more info than you need at the moment.

Comment: Hi JGNI, appreciate for your info. Yes , this is the data structure  that I want.  I will go and read the perldsc that you gave. Thank you!